# Where can I find useful R tutorials with various implementations?

Tags: r, references

I'm using [**R**](http://www.r-project.org/) and the manuals on the R site are really informative. However, I'd like to see some more examples and implementations with R which can help me develop my knowledge faster. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is really a Stackoverflow question as it has to do with learning the R programming language.  With the current wording the question is only associated with statistics by virtue of R's focus on statistical analysis.

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close it just yet- there could be a good question in there.  Perhaps something like "Where can I find useful tutorials that focus on putting statistical concepts into practice using a tool such as R?" or "Where can I find useful tutorials that teach statistics by example using tools such as R?"

Comment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-much-programming-here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick R site is basic, but quite nice for start http://www.statmethods.net/index.html .

Answer (score 4):

[R bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/) has been steadily supplying me with a lot of good pragmatic content.
From the author:

```
R-Bloggers.com is a central hub (e.g: A blog aggregator) of content 
collected from bloggers who write about R (in English). 
The site will help R bloggers and users to connect and follow 
the “R blogosphere”.
```

Answer (score 4):

Another great resource is [the LearnR blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/), which went through an extensive study of visualizations with lattice and ggplot2.

Answer (score 2):

R is designed around ideas such as "reproducible research" and "trustworthy software", as John Chambers says [in his excellent book "Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R"](http://books.google.com/books?id=UXneuOIvhEAC&printsec=frontcover).

One of the best ways to learn R is to look at the wealth of source code that available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) (with 2461 packages and counting).  Simple `install.packages`, load a `library()`, and start browsing the code.

Answer (score 2):

I found this rather helpful: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Verzani-SimpleR.pdf